# Movie about ethnic massacre where hero played by famous African-American actor protects people in a big house

Tags: identify-this-movie

Way back in Year (class) 8 (6 years ago) I watched a movie during what I remember was either Religious Education or English Language way back in 2011. The movie however seemed to be 10 years older like it seemed like a movie from the 2000s (it was in colour).

The language spoken was definitely English because I remember the hero of the movie was an African-American actor who was pretty famous at the time. Thinking now the movie reminds me of the purge but much more older and set in a country like Africa or South America).

Anyway here are the key facts I know/think I know about this movie:

- There is a massacre that happens due to an assassination
- The people leading the massacre suspects certain groups of people in their country/community to do it
- Before the massacre happens a friend of the hero (I think he becomes the main protagonist near the end) is caught harboring weapons (mostly cheap butcher knives I think) and he tips off to the hero that there will be a massacre and that his family should move country.
- The massacre starts off slow, at the start a few houses are set on fire and the hero starts to worry.
- Local police and soldiers (probably corrupt) don't intervene with these people who go round house to house killing **certain types of people**
- I think that the hero of the movie doesn't have to worry because either he is friends with the leaders of the rebels **or are not** those who are persecuted by these soldiers and rogue civilians
- The hero believes what these people are doing is wrong and harbors people in his mansion/shelter (a building of importance because I remember white soldiers protected the place)
- Eventually the soldiers leave and what happens next is the hero meets the person mentioned before who has a sex dungeon full of slaves and on the way there the hero sees loads of dead bodies on the side walk
- I believe that the hero said to the people inside the shelter that if the hero does not return that they should suicide? or something like that
- The rest is hazy but I believe what happens is like special operatives come and save them by clearing an area that used to be controlled by the people committing the massacre
- The main bit I know is that the point of this massacre is ethnic cleansing or to make some kind of statement.

The teacher had it on DVD so I don't know what time the movie was showing in cinemas.

Appearances of the characters:
I don't know much about this other than that 90 percent of the characters other than the soldiers protecting the mansion were African or African-American.

Comment: This is a solid identification request!

Comment: "...it seemed like a movie from the 2000s (it was in colour)" Fun fact: color movies were not uncommon in the 1990s ;-)

Comment: Well because I am someone born in 2000's whenever I hear "the 90s" I think of black and white film and ballroom dancing for some reason

Comment: Metro Blooming - The first color movies go back to the silent film era.  Hollywood transitioned to color between the 1930s and the 1960s, mostly in the 1950s. The 3 major US TV networks switched to all color programming in the 1966-1967 seasons.  Other countries may have taken longer to catch up but I doubt that many countries had a majority of films made in black and white as late as the 1990s.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds like it may be [Hotel Rwanda](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0395169/) a 2004-movie based on the real 1994 Rwandan massacres and the heroic acts of [Paul Rusesabagina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Rusesabagina).

I don't remember several of the details you mention, but the overall arc definitely fits (the Rwandan massacre) and several of the other details fit:

- The movie starred Don Cheadle and the majority of the cast were African / African-American
- The hotel could easily be remembered as a mansion/shelter

Comment: For more info, that movie was related to one of many [Rwandan genocide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rwandan_genocide) experiences.

Comment: wow I forgot that it happened because of a real event, that makes sense now because we watched it in RE when we were learning about forgiveness and religious views on genocides (and how they should act)!